# How to give weights to training instances liblinear for logistic regression

Tags: regression, matlab

I am using liblinear for logistic regression. I want to give weights to my training instances since the data is unbalanced. I am currently trying to use liblinear in matlab. How can I do it. I don't see any option to provide the weights to the training instances. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for software help.

Comment: Simply resample instances you want to give higher weight.